# Setting the CLASSPATH to run Duke correctly

Tags: java, classpath

When I try to run Duke (a open source reduplication program) I get java class not found errors. I have done the following to add the proper files to the Classpath.

This is what the developer says to do in order to run the program :
"To run Duke you need an XML configuration file. You also need to put duke-**.jar and lucene-**.jar on the classpath."

To run Duke, give the command:

```
java no.priv.garshol.duke.Duke
```

after learning about the classpath this is what I came up with:

```
Kyles-MBP:~ kyleanderson$ export CLASSPATH="/Users/kyleanderson/Desktop/duke-1.2/duke-**.jar:/Users/kyleanderson/Desktop/duke-1.2/lucene-**.jar"
Kyles-MBP:~ kyleanderson$ java no.priv.garshol.duke.Duke
```

when I try and run the main class, I get the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: no/priv/garshol/duke/Duke
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: no.priv.garshol.duke.Duke
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I have looked around here a bunch and nothing seems to answer my question.

Comment: Are you sure the wildcard syntax in your CLASSPATH is correct?

Comment: I think so, I used the same syntax the developer suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this this:

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Users/kyleanderson/Desktop/duke-1.2/*:/Users/kyleanderson/Desktop/duke-1.2/*
java no.priv.garshol.duke.Duke
```

Comment: I think it was the CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH: part that I missed. anyways It seems to be working

Comment: not only $CLASSPATH, for wildcard, do NOT use it with any other pattern to match, just: /your/jar/dir/*